# Saving a data to my database did not reflect in my database using Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am having a problem when saving data in my SQL Server. Let's just say I have to tables in my database and the first table which is the users can successfully reflect in the database. However, when I am trying to add information on my 2nd table which is Agency, it did not save in my database even though it returns a value after debugging.

Meaning, my connection is working perfectly. I can't find where I made a mistake.

Here are my injected services:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<LoginController>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<AdminController>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<NavMenuController>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
```

And here's my code in saving data for user and agency which is my service

```
using BlazorProject.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BlazorProject.ServiceController
{
    public class AdminController
    {
        private IDbContextFactory<DbContextLayer> _dbContextFactory;

        public AdminController(IDbContextFactory<DbContextLayer> dbContextFactory)
        { 
            _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory; 
        }

        // added for User registration
        public void AddUsers(Users users)
        {
            using (var ctx = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                var userId = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == null);

                if (userId == null)
                {
                    ctx.Users.Add(users);
                    ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("User Id already exists!");
                }
            }
        }

        // add Agency
        public void AddAgency(Agency agency)
        {
            using (var ctx = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                var agencyId = ctx.Agency.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AgencyId == null);

                if (agencyId == null)
                {
                    ctx.Agency.Add(agency);
                    ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Agency Id already exists!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show the newly added in my database but it seems no matter how I tried to change the way to save the information, it will not reflect in the database.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use async methods within a synchronous context.  Your code completes before `ctx.SaveChangesAsync` completes.  The add is almost certainly happening, you're just not waiting for it to complete before you try and display the results.

Either use the synchronous blocking `ctx.SaveChanges()` or declare your methods as async and await the `SaveChangesAsync`.

Here's a refactored version of your `AddAgency`` method:

```cs
public async ValueTask AddAgencyAsync(Agency agency)
{
    // You no longer need to wrap this.  The compiler sorts it out for you scoped to the method
    using var ctx = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

    // Use Any to detect if a record already exists
    var recordExists = ctx.Agency.Any(x => x.AgencyId == agency.AgencyId);

    if (recordExists)
        throw new Exception("Agency Id already exists!");

    ctx.Agency.Add(agency);
    // check here to see that you have 1 update
    var updates = await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

You could also refactor the command to return a result with status information so you don't resort to throwing an exception.

Here's some example code

```cs
public sealed record CommandResult : IDataResult
{ 
    public bool Successful { get; init; }
    public string? Message { get; init; }

    private CommandResult() { }

    public static CommandResult Success(string? message = null)
        => new CommandResult { Successful = true, Message= message};

    public static CommandResult Failure(string message)
        => new CommandResult { Message = message};
}
```

```cs
public async ValueTask<CommandResult> AddAgencyAsync(Agency agency)
{
    using var ctx = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

    var recordExists = ctx.Agency.Any(x => x.AgencyId == agency.AgencyId);

    if (recordExists)
        return CommandResult.Failure("Agency Id already exists!")
    
    ctx.Agency.Add(agency);
    var updates = await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return updates == 1
        ? CommandResult.Success()
        : CommandResult.Failure("There was a problem adding the record");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. I already solved it and the problem lies in my PK. Thank you so much.